# Read text file in pyspark and sparksubmit

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

Assuming I run a python shell **(file1.py)** which take a text file as a parameter. that I run it as the following:

```
python file1.py textfile1.txt
```

Inside file1.py the following code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
....

#I can read the file using the follwoing command
sc = SparkContext()
inputfile= sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
```

What is the required modifications I must do to make file1.py run without problems?

But pyspark doesn't work with me, usually, I am using spark-submit!so it give me the following error when run using spark-submit in local mode

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noorhadoop/Desktop/folder1/file1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/platform.py", line 909, in <module>
    "system node release version machine processor")
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 381, in namedtuple
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import urllib.parse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 227, in <module>
    _DefragResultBase = namedtuple('DefragResult', 'url fragment')
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 381, in namedtuple
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noorhadoop/Desktop/folder1/file1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/platform.py", line 909, in <module>
    "system node release version machine processor")
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 381, in namedtuple
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'
hduser@noorhadoop-virtual-machine:/usr/local/spark$ ./bin/spark-submit --master local[3] /home/noorhadoop/Desktop/folder1/file1.py  /home/noorhadoop/Desktop/folder1/simple1.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noorhadoop/Desktop/folder1/file1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/platform.py", line 909, in <module>
    "system node release version machine processor")
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 381, in namedtuple
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import urllib.parse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 227, in <module>
    _DefragResultBase = namedtuple('DefragResult', 'url fragment')
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 381, in namedtuple
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noorhadoop/Desktop/folder1/file1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/platform.py", line 909, in <module>
    "system node release version machine processor")
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 381, in namedtuple
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the error

Comment: I added the error to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt post error messages, so it hard to know exact but `sc.textFile` expects full path of file either on HDFS or local file system.

for example, if you are running spark in local mode , you will have to pass arguments with spark-submit as -

```
spark-submit \
--master local[*] \
--/path/to/file1.py \
"file://path/to/textfile1.txt"
```

or if you are running on cluster, give full hdfs path as argument

```
spark-submit \
--master spark://localhost:7077 \
--/path/to/file1.py \
"hdfs://localhost:9000/path/to/textfile1.txt"
```

Comment: I followed your example to run using spark-submit in local mode  .. but it gave me error for importing sparkconext from spark (I added the error to the question )

Comment: Oh, you are using python3.6. This is not supported by latest version of spark yet. There is open JIRA for fixing it but as of now you will have to downgrade your python to 3.5 . Here is JIRA link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019

Comment: I tried python 2.7 and the same error! does it not supported also? @Pushkr

Comment: How did you tried with python2.7, did you execute command like `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7` before doing spark-submit ?Your error trace will show which python is being selected...

Comment: I change the default python version in bashrc and test it via python --version,,, and run spark0submit again, give same error above

Comment: Oh I just understand you, although python --version gave me 2.7 but in the error trace it still show 3.6!  I changed the default in bashrc and profile!

Comment: I changed python version used in all required places (different users) and it works now! thanks.